# Capturing Results from Stored Procedures having Conditional select with EF6

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I m using a stored procedure to call in `EF6`, which results varies depend upon conditions satisfied. How to capture such results in `EF6`?

### Sample Procedure :

```
create procedure udsp_get_category
(
    @a int =0
)
as
if @a = 1
Begin
    select top 1 pk_cat_id,cat_name,cat_is_active from category_master
End
Else if @a = 0
Begin 
    select top 1 pk_cattp_id,cattp_name,cattp_is_active from category_type_master 
End
Else 
Begin
    select -1 as no_result
End
```

result totally differs for any condition, please guide for capturing such result set in `Entity Framework`! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on what your models look like. Assuming you have a category model and have mapped the field names accordingly something like this would be a start:

```
public Category GetCategoryById(int categoryId)
{
    Category category;

    using (var context = new NorthwindData())
    {
        SqlParameter categoryParam = new SqlParameter("@a", categoryId);
        category = context.Database.SqlQuery<Category>("udsp_get_category @a", categoryParam).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return category;
}
```

There are a lot of good articles out there on EF with stored procedures. http://www.lucbos.net/2012/03/calling-stored-procedure-with-entity.html

Answer (score 1):

This will only work well with EF if you all queries have the same shape. For instance:

```
create procedure udsp_get_category
(
    @a int =0
)
as
if @a = 1
Begin
    select top 1 pk_cat_id as [Id],
                 cat_name as [Name],
                 cat_is_active as [Active],
                 1 as [IsMaster]
    from category_master
End
Else if @a = 0
Begin 
    select top 1 pk_cattp_id as [Id],
                 cattp_name as [Name],
                 cattp_is_active as [Active]
                 0 as [IsMaster]
    from category_type_master 
End
Else 
Begin
    select -1 as [Id],
           null as [Name],
           null as [Active]
           -1 as [IsMaster]
End
```

Now you can capture the results in a class having `Id`, `Name`, `Active`, and `IsMaster` as properties.